# SQLite - Left Join with Substr

Tags: sqlite, left-join, substr

```
select distinct substr(value,2,4),summary 
from ticket_custom 
LEFT JOIN ticket On ticket_custom.substr(value,2,4) = ticket.id 
where name = "parent" AND value <> 0
```

I have a table ticket_custom where the ticket-number has a hastag in front of the ticketnumber (e.g. "#4567"), but in the table ticket, the ticketnumber is saved without this hashtag ("4567").
I would like to left join these two tables and would like to use the "summary"-value of the table ticket right next to the ticket-number without the #. I tried the above query, but I am getting an error. How can I combine substr = using the ticketnumber without the # with a left join? Or is there another way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be doing `substr(ticket_custom.value,2,4)` instead of `ticket_custom.substr(value,2,4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing `substr(ticket_custom.value,2)` instead of `ticket_custom.substr(value,2,4)` (syntax was incorrect, and string length isn't guaranteed only to be 5 chars)

So your query should look like:

```
select distinct substr(value,2),summary 
from ticket_custom 
LEFT JOIN ticket On substr(ticket_custom.value,2) = ticket.id 
where name = "parent" AND value <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax for the function [`substr()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr):

```
On substr(ticket_custom.value,2,4) = ticket.id
```

or

```
On substr(ticket_custom.value,2) = ticket.id
```

if `ticket_custom.value` contains only 5 characters.
In this case (only 5 characters) you can use `replace()`:

```
On replace(ticket_custom.value, '#', '') = ticket.id
```

or simply:

```
On ticket_custom.value = '#' || ticket.id
```